# Insert a parameter in awk script

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have this code. **I would like to add a parameter** (name of an airport) **to said code**. So, given a name of an airport, I'd get the same output but only for that given parameter.

**Code:**

Obtain the percentage of delayed flights, the total number of flights delayed and the total number of flights, on each day of the week.

```
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
FNR > 1 {
    total[$2]++; if ($6) delay[$2]++ }
END {
  print "\"weekday\"", "\"percentage_delayed\"", "\"delayed\"", "\"total_flights\""
  for (day in total) { print day, delay[day] / total[day] * 100, delay[day], total[day]}
  }
```

**Input:**

Column 3 and 4 are the names of the airports.

```
"DAY_OF_MONTH","DAY_OF_WEEK","ORIGIN","DEST","DEP_TIME","DEP_DEL15","CANCELLED","DIVERTED","DISTANCE"
1,Tuesday,ORD,GRB,1003,0.00,0.00,0.00,322.248
1,Tuesday,TUL,ORD,1027,0.00,0.00,0.00,1083.42
1,Tuesday,EWR,TYS,1848,0.00,0.00,0.00,1168.61
```

**Output:**

```
"weekday", "percentage_delayed", "delayed", "total_flights"
Tuesday,10.7912,446,4133
Moday,10.2564,336,3276
Friday,26.6401,735,2759
```

How can I add a parameter to the code, so it only shows the output for that given parameter?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. You say "given the name of an airport" - do you want to include the airport only when it is the origin, only when it is the destination, or in both cases? Please edit your post to clarify, and also include what you already tried and where you failed, so that contributors don't suggest solutions you already know won't work ... Also, I don't seem to arrive at your output with the progrem you provided; could you make sure the code is complete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ awk -v origin='ORD' -v dest='GRB' '
  BEGIN { FS=OFS= "," }
  FNR > 1 && $3==origin && $4==dest { total[$2]++; if ($6) delay[$2]++ }
  END {
      print "weekday", "percentage_delayed", "delayed", "total_flights"
      for (day in total) 
          print day, delay[day] / total[day] * 100, delay[day]+0, total[day]
  }' infile
```

At above `-v origin='ORD'` and `-v dest='GRB'` are defined as parameters to the awk script, change them based on your need.